# react-svg test env: can't set src by import state

Tags: reactjs, svg, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to write test for a component that uses `react-svg`
but In the test I can't set the src from an `import` statement,
The `screen.debug()` doen't print the svg content

Any idea how to mock the src of `react-svg` in test env?
(I searched already and found similar questions but none of them helped me)

Example:

pic.svg

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle r="50" cx="50" cy="50" fill="tomato"/>
</svg>
```

test.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import { ReactSVG } from 'react-svg';
import pic from './pic.svg';

describe('', () => {
    it('should render svg', () => {
        render(<ReactSVG src={pic} />)
        screen.debug()
        // ...
    })
})
```

Here in the output I don't see the content of pic.svg

```html
 console.log
    <body>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div
              data-src="pic.svg"
              src=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```